# sibling selector with :before doesn't work in styled-component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, styled-components

How to use this

```
li+li:before {
  padding: 8px;
  color: black;
  content: "/\00a0";
}
```

in styled-component? I tried to convert this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_breadcrumbs

to styled-component but it's not working.

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-pasteur-mkmyh?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the `content` seems to be the culprit. The rest of the code is fine.

Instead of `/\00a0` it should be `/\\00a0`. It seems to be a styled-components specific issue.

Here's a short quote as an explanation, the source has more in depth discussion.

> Basically because you write CSS in JS you have to escape twice - once for JS parser and once for CSS one.

[Source/GitHub](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1601#issuecomment-549122908)

Full working code:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function Namaste() {
  return (
    <UL>
      <li>
        <a href="/#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/#">Pictures</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/#">Summer 15</a>
      </li>
      <li>Italy</li>
    </UL>
  );
}

const UL = styled.ul`
  padding: 10px 16px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #eee;

  li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red;
  }
  li + li:before {
    padding: 8px;
    color: black;
    content: "/\\00a0";
  }
  li a {
    color: #0275d8;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
`;
```